# Community-facing Lightning Web Component fails to deploy

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, experience-bundle

I'm having an issue deploying a new LWC to a new page in my community. Using experience bundles, I am deploying a new view and route. The view has a new LWC on it with the following meta:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property
                name="recordId"
                type="String"
                label="Record Id"
                description="Automatically bind the page's record id to the component variable"
                default="{!recordId}" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

The error I'm getting is quite confusing because it seems to think the component I'm deploying is an aura component:
`CommunityName    Site.com    0   0   Implement "forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" for the Aura component c:newLWC with ID e08a7223-e4e5-440e-86df-496f0c72528f and try again.`

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Update - this was caused by a malformed package.xml file. I was missing an opening `types` tag. I would have expected to see an error message about the package on deployment, but I guess there is none.